# GET path not accepting 'dot' in it

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have router path with a '.' in it, my path is `downloads/pass.pkpass`

I have defined the path in web.php as the following

`$router->get('downloads/pass.pkpass', 'PassServerController@downloadPass');`

but somehow it's not working. if I remove the '.' it's working fine. what might be the problem here?

It's was working before recently I updated lumen after that it's not working.

Comment: why you need dot in your url use "-" instead

Comment: Agree with afsal c . using a dot will only confuse servers and browsers since what normally follows is a domain ending (".com") or file extension when downloading files

Comment: @afsalc - it's a file to download, the file is creating on the fly.

Comment: Look at this: `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-name-prefixes`

Comment: It's a file I am setting some headers before make it download

Comment: use `return response()->download($pathToFile);` this download file

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara - I'm not able to call the function because of the dot in the path.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` is the string concatenation operator in PHP.

example

```
<?php

$string1 = "Test";
$string2 = "working!";
$string = $string1 . $string2;

echo $string;

?>
```

this will print "Test working!"

You can get your route by this may be

```
$router->get('downloads/pass.'.'pkpass', 'PassServerController@downloadPass');
```

> But this is some kind of hack we can say.

You can use `_` instead of `.` parameter that will work for sure.

Comment: $router->get('downloads/pass'.'pkpass', 'PassServerController@downloadPass'); Iam not sure try this

Comment: `_` is working for me but not `.` It was woking fine before recently I updated my lumen after that the issue started.

Comment: I have researched and found that using  `.` is not the proper way. @Unnikrishnan

Comment: @ChiragPatel -  so what is the beast practice for a download file URL? If I have a on the fly PDF generation code how I should define the download path?